# CentOS system start error in VMware worstation

Tags: centos, vmware

CentOS system installed on VMware 15.5 worstation which installed on my windows system computer. several days ago, it worked well.But there was an error appeared when starting CentsOS in the VMware workstation shown as the picture below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j61NR.png)

Comment: The recent Windows updates screwed my VMware as well.... (But I had 14, so I upgraded to 15). Have you tried to copy your VM and run the copy?

Comment: thank u .my edtiton has been 15.5, i wii have a try